# Can't find class org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, pkcs#7, smime

I have to load and verify pkcs7 file in java. I found many tutorials that talk about CMSSignedData but I can't find the package `org.bouncycastle.cms.*`, there is just `org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.*` and it doesn't contain the class CMSSignedData.

I downloaded these libraries: `bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar`, `bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar` and `bcmail-jdk15on-152.jar`.

Is there other package that I didn't add ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, the `bcpkix-jdk15on-152.jar` was missing. The class CMSSignedData is embedded in this jar.

Most tutorials that i followed mentioned that only the three jar above are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Add to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.68</version>
</dependency>
```